# Old script on systemV

Tags: shell-script

I want to add a group for permit user belong to group to shutdown the machine
system is old sysv unix,with old bourne sh.
I did

```
{
groufind=`groups|grep system|awk '{print $2}'`
}
        groupscheck
        eval `id  |  /usr/bin/sed 's/[^a-z0-9=].*//'`
        if [ "$LOGNAME != "root"  -o  $groufind != "system" ];
        then
                echo "$0:  Only root or system group can run /sbin/shutdown."
                exit 2
        fi
else
        echo "$0:  can't check user id."
        exit 2
```

But doesn't work,exit with error

```
/sbin/shutdown: test: argument expected
```

Where is wrong?

---

Sorry for incomplete script,i want a work like this

```
    groupscheck()
{
groufind=`groups|grep system|awk '{print $2}'`
who=`id|cut -d "(" -f 2|cut -d ")" -f 1`
root=root
system=system
}
        groupscheck
        if [ $who !=  $root  -o  $groufind !=  $system ];
then
        echo "OK"
        else
        echo    "no"
fi
```

If root or user in system exec the script give OK otherwise
no,but why don't work?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your script is supposed to do, but for starters: 1) it definitely doesn't add groups anywhere, 2) has a hanging `else` on 3rd line from the end, 3) doesn't define `groupscheck` (which I don't think is a standard tool), 4) doesn't call `/sbin/shutdown` anywhere - so it probably actually is `/sbin/shutdown`, but incomplete (which is likely since it didn't complain about the superfluous `else`, and is missing the usual `#!` at the beginning). How would you expect anybody to help you with that?

Comment: Delete Your Script, and Consider using [this method instead](http://www.superuser.com/questions/666687/linux-shutdown-permission). This method is easier to script. Otherwise, the user you create needs to be in the pm group IIRC

Comment: I merged your edit into the question. I tried to clean it up, but I really have no idea what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing quote... You should really check your code, at least with a syntax highlighter. This line...

```
if [ "$LOGNAME != "root"  -o  $groufind != "system" ];
```

Should be:

```
if [ "$LOGNAME" != "root"  -o  $groufind != "system" ];
```

Now for the rest, I'm gonna have to guess because your code sample is nothing close to helpful:

- This weird scope at the beginning is probably `groupchecks`'s definition.
- I'm not really sure why you're calling `eval`.
- I don't why you added an `else` branch in the end, since it has no matching `if`.

Anyway, I'd say your script could be simplified as:

```
#!/bin/sh

groups $LOGNAME | grep system > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 -a "$LOGNAME" != "root" ]; then
    echo "$0:  Only root or system group can run /sbin/shutdown."
    exit 1
else
    echo "$0: Shutdown possible."
    exit 0
fi
```

... even though I'm not quite sure if all of this runs on an old SYSv4 system.